# Vue 3 -> Custom v-title directive (wrap component inside other component)

Tags: vuejs3, directive

I'am using Vue 3 and I have a component that uses Popper.js to show nice tooltip.
It's used like this:

```html
<Pop text="some tooltip message">
    <div>this is element with tooltip</div>
</Pop>
```

[image]

I want to make it custom directive but I cant find any examples, just very simple custom directives like:

```js
app.directive('focus', {
    mounted(el) {
        el.focus()
    }
})
```

I want it to work somewhat like this:

```html
<div v-pop="some tooltip message">this is element with tooltip</div>
```

But I don't quite understand how programmatically create the Pop component and how set the 'el' to it's slot and render.

Does someone know or know some tutorial please?

Comment: this [page](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/custom-directives.html#_3-x-syntax) can help you.

Comment: thx :) .. but I've already read the whole page before I've wrote this up - I've read many pages in doc about this.

Comment: I've probably found it -> render functions!
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html